# Перепрыгивание на страницу с помощью редиректа

Tags: .htaccess, mod_rewrite

Доброго всем времени суток, господа.

Есть редирект. Настроен не мной, и править нежелательно, в меру того, как там все наверчено. хочется сделать одну маленькую модификацию.

`при адресе http://www.***.ru/specrazdel/
нужно перепрыгнуть http://www.***.ru/specrazdel/1`

Можно ли как-то дописать это в редирект в самом конце, что бы шел переход?

p.s. Вот как пример - есть накая штука директори индекс, т.е. основная страница, на которую нужно перейти при заходе на сайт. в моем случае - нужно перепрыгнуть с не основной, на другую не основную, так, что бы это еще и другие страницы не задело.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Redirect 301 /specrazdel/ http://www.***.ru/specrazdel/1`

Comment: я просто добавил эту строчку в конец .htaccess файла, там где заканчиваются правила для редиректов, ест-но дописав свой адрес. не сработало. я что то не так сделал? или может там еще что то нужно дописать?

Comment: Я не экстросенс и не могу знать что просано у вас в .htaccess файле.